# How to get the actual text size rendered with minimumScaleFactor

Tags: swift, swiftui

Text with [`minimumScaleFactor(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/minimumscalefactor(_:)) would scale the text smaller than the font size hard-coded for a Text view based on the space available the parent view offered.

> Sets the minimum amount that text in this view scales down to fit in the available space.

**If a smaller font is used how to access the actual font size rendered?**. An alternative title could be "how to know the actual scale factor is used?"

```
            Text("Foo")
                .font(
                    .system(
                        size: 999,
                        weight: .regular,
                        design: .monospaced
                    )
                )
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.05)
```

**Update**
Found a great article online that talks about "Auto Resizable Text Size in SwiftUI" might worth to share, https://malauch.com/posts/auto-resizable-text-size-in-swiftui/

Comment: Is it answers your question?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way. You get some UI states after the layout phase using GeometryReader, but we don't have something akin like a "FontReader". You may try some of the approaches already attempted in UIKit for the same problem after getting the size and text of your Text view.